# How to send form data to CommonsMultipartFile Controller post method without attaching a file?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller post method when I try to upload data along with the file attached.It works fine.
But I want to know how to handle when no file is attached and how to read the data.
Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="saveimage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveimage( @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();

String uploadPath = context.getRealPath(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);
System.out.println(uploadPath);    

System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());


byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
BufferedOutputStream stream =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadPath + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename())));
stream.write(bytes);
stream.flush();
stream.close();
EmpFileBean e=new EmpFileBean();
e.setFile(file.getOriginalFilename());
e.setTextdata(request.getParameter("textdata"));
     dao.saveImage(e);
     request.setAttribute("img_name", e.getFile());
return new ModelAndView("uploadform","filesuccess","File successfully saved!");
}
```

My JSP looks like:

```
  <form:form method="post" action="saveimage" attribute="EmpFileBean" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  <p><label for="image">Choose Image</label></p>  
  <p><input name="file" id="fileToUpload" type="file" path="file"/></p> 
  <p><label for="textdata">Enter User Name</label></p>  

  <p><input name="textdata" id="textdata" type="text" path="textdata"/></p>  
   <%
  if(request.getAttribute("img_name")!=null)
  {

  %>
  <img alt="" src="images/<%=request.getAttribute("img_name")%>">
  <%} %>

 <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>  
  </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@RequestParam` for multipart file upload, then if the field is empty, then request is not accepted by controller saying some error message

> the parameter "file" is not present in the request  like:

However you can use a Model class as a `@ModelAttribute` and inside the model class put your multi-part file object and its `setter`, `getter`. Perhaps this class looks something like that,

```
public class FileBean {

    private CommonsMultipartFile file;

    public CommonsMultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(CommonsMultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

And from controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="saveimage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveimage( @ModelAttribute FileBean file,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
----------------------- your controller code---------
}
```

Let me know the status.